# UISearchBar loses focus

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I've got a UISearchBar and a seperat UITableView. When the user types something in the SearchBar I call my API and then reload the TableView to display the new results. Everytime the TableView reloads the SearchBar loses focus. How can I prevent this?

I tried `[_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];` but it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Thanks for your help.

(Edit) Code I used to reload the data:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController updateWithObjectList:_newList removeMissing:YES];

- (void)updateWithObjectList:(NSArray *)objectList removeMissing:(BOOL)removeMissing {
    if (removeMissing) {
        [self removeObjectList:[_objects allValues]];
    }
    [self addObjectList:objectList];
}
```

Comment: How are you reloading the data in that tableview?  Post the code that you are using to do this.  This is not normal behavior.

Comment: Somebody else wrote that, but I think it's about that what I've added to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are dealing with a hand built (non `CoreData`) array for the `TablevView` datasource.  If that is the case, why are you using a `fetchedResultsController`?

Why not rebuild the array (datasource) for the TableView and then just call

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

(substitute whatever you have called your `TableView` for myTableView).  If you need a complete example of how to do this, let me know.